# how to add 2 element in nested array from one root element using JOLT specification?

Tags: arrays, json, jolt

Input:

```
{
"k1": "v1",
"k2": "v2",
"event": "SUMMARY"
}
```

Expected output:

```
{
  "k1": "v1",
  "k2": "v2",
  "event": "SUMMARY",
  "arr": [
    {
      "k1": "v1",
      "key": "first"
    },
    {
      "k2": "v2",
      "key": "second"
    },
    {
      "summary1": "s1",
      "key": "SUMMARY"
    },
    {
      "summary1": "s2",
      "key": "SUMMARY"
    }
  ]
}
```

For each 'k1' and 'k2', respective array element should be added as

```
{
"k2": "v2",
"key": "second"
}
```

For when event = "SUMMARY", respective 2 elements should be added as

```
{
"summary1": "s1",
"key": "SUMMARY"
},
{
"summary2": "s2",
"key": "SUMMARY"
}
```

Please help with JOLT specification

Answer (score 1):

Since you gave input and output based on that i written 
one function in javascript.

{
"k1": "v1",
"k2": "v2",
"event": "SUMMARY"
}

Well that function will work only for above input

and also you have to mention that whether u want output in which language...

```js
//Input

var obj = {
    "k1": "v1",
    "k2": "v2",
    "event": "SUMMARY"
}

//funciton calling 
obj["arr"] = checkThis(obj);



//output
console.log(obj)




function checkThis(obj) {
    var arr = [];
    Object.keys(obj)
        .forEach(function eachKey(key) {
            if (key == "k1") {
                var tempObj = {}
                tempObj["k1"] = obj[key];
                tempObj["key"] = "first";
                arr.push(tempObj)
            } else if (key == "k2") {
                var tempObj = {}
                tempObj["k2"] = obj[key];
                tempObj["key"] = "second";
                arr.push(tempObj)
            } else if (key == "event") {
                var tempObj1 = {}
                var tempObj2 = {}
                tempObj1["summary1"] = "s1";
                tempObj1["key"] = obj[key];
                tempObj2["summary1"] = "s2";
                tempObj2["key"] = obj[key];
                arr.push(tempObj1)
                arr.push(tempObj2)
            }
        });                        
return arr;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for trying out, but as mentioned in question title, i require JOLT specification to process this not javascript code.
For JOLT reference refer: https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt